# how to use toggleclass to show only current active item and how to get the active classname

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui

I have created dynamic boostrap card which record player. I am a beginner with Jquery and CSS/scss.

I have will have multiple boostrap cards generated depending on the data in DB. For sake of simplicity, I have written only 2 boostrap cards in example below. My question is how do I stop a playing record player(vinly to flip back to album->is-not-playing class) when another one is click to play. In other words, only 1 record player is allowed to play at any given time with vinly animation. If a user clicks on play of another card, the currently player will stop and flip back to album cover with the toggleclass. The code has only animation part,not the actual player. How do i get the current toggleclass name?

```
      <div class="container-fluid">
    <div id="content">
      <div class="music-player-container is-not-playing" id="1mpc">
        <div class="card card-inverse" id="1card">
          <div class="card-header" id="1cardHeader">
            <div class="top">
              <i id="1fav" class="favtoggle fa not-liked"></i>
              <i id="1pl" class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div id="1album" class="album">
            <div class="album-art">
              <img class="card-img-top" src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/81kZdGYO%2ByL._SL1500_.jpg" alt="Card image cap">
              <div class="card-img-overlay h-100 d-flex flex-column justify-content-center text-center">
                <span class="control-play" id="1control-play" data-ctype="audio/mp3" data-src="http://localhost:49544/Albums/The_Beatles/Greatest_Hits/hey jude.mp3" title="Play"></span>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="vinyl" id="1vinyl"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="card-footer">
            <span class="text-ellipsis text-left">hey jude</span>
            <small class=" text-left text-ellipsis text-xs text-muted">Abbey Road</small>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-2nd one->


        <div class="music-player-container is-not-playing" id="2mpc">
          <div class="card card-inverse" id="2card">
            <div class="card-header" id="2cardHeader">
              <div class="top">
                <i id="2fav" class="favtoggle fa not-liked"></i>
                <i id="2pl" class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div id="2album" class="album">
              <div class="album-art">
                <img class="card-img-top" src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/81kZdGYO%2ByL._SL1500_.jpg" alt="Card image cap">
                <div class="card-img-overlay h-100 d-flex flex-column justify-content-center text-center">
                  <span class="control-play" id="2control-play" data-ctype="audio/mp3" data-src="http://localhost:49544/Albums/The_Beatles/Greatest_Hits/hey jude.mp3" title="Play"></span>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="vinyl" id="2vinyl"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="card-footer">
              <span class="text-ellipsis text-left">hey jude</span>
              <small class=" text-left text-ellipsis text-xs text-muted">Abbey Road</small>
            </div>
          </div>

        </div>

      </div>
```

javascript:

```
var $div = $('#content');
     var playButton = $('.control-play');
     playButton.on('click', function(e) {
       //alert(e.target.id);
       var $musiPlayerContainer = $div.find('#' + e.target.id + 'mpc');
       var $vinyl = $div.find('#' + e.target.id + 'vinyl');

       $(".music-player-container").not($('#' + e.target.id + 'mpc')).toggleClass('is-playing', false);
       $('#' + e.target.id + 'mpc').toggleClass('is-playing', true);
       e.stopPropagation();
     });
```

CSS

```
        /* CSS used here will be applied after bootstrap.css */


    /* CSS used here will be applied after bootstrap.css */


    /*@import '../../bourbon/_bourbon.scss';*/


    /*@import "../../bourbon-bitters/_bitters.scss";*/

    @import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:400,300,500);
    * {
      -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
      -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    *:before,
    *:after {
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }


    /*@import "compass/css3";*/


    /*@import "../../bourbon-bitters/mixins/_base.scss";*/


    /*@mixin filter($function: none) {
    //   @warn "This old mixin is deprecated!";

    @include _bourbon-deprecate-for-prefixing("filter");
    // <filter-function> [<filter-function]* | none
    @include prefixer(filter, $function, webkit spec);
    }*/

    body {
      background-color: #fff;
      color: #515044;
      font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
    }

    .music-player-container {
      -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
      -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
      -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
      -o-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
      transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
      display: inline-block;
      height: 220px;
      position: relative;
      max-width: 130px;
      margin-left: 70px;
      margin-top: 170px;
    }

    .music-player {
      background-color: #fff;
      height: 120px;
      padding: 40px 200px 40px 40px;
      position: absolute;
      text-align: right;
      width: 125px;
      z-index: 3;
    }

    .player-content-container {
      -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
      -moz-transform: translateY(-50%);
      -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
      -o-transform: translateY(-50%);
      transform: translateY(-50%);
      top: 50%;
      position: relative;
    }

    .artist-name {
      font-size: 28px;
      font-weight: normal;
      margin: 0 0 0.75em 0;
    }

    .album-title {
      font-weight: 200;
      font-size: 24px;
      margin: 0 0 1.75em 0;
    }

    .song-title {
      font-size: 18px;
      font-weight: 200;
      margin: 0 0 1.5em 0;
    }

    .album {
      box-shadow: 3px 3px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.65);
      height: 120px;
      /*margin-left: 250px;
      margin-top: 27px;*/
      position: relative;
      width: 125px;
      z-index: 10;
    }

    .album-art {
      background: #fff center no-repeat;
      height: 120px;
      position: relative;
      width: 125px;
      z-index: 10;
    }

    .card-img {
      background: #fff center no-repeat;
      height: 120px;
      position: relative;
      width: 125px;
      z-index: 10;
    }

    .card-img > .card-img-overlay {
      background: #e0eaec center no-repeat;
      z-index: 10;
    }

    .vinyl {
      -webkit-animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
      -moz-animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
      animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
      -webkit-transition: all 500ms;
      -moz-transition: all 500ms;
      transition: all 500ms;
      background-image: url("https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/83141/vinyl.png"), url("http://localhost:49544/Albums/The_Beatles/Greatest_Hits/Album_Cover/IMG_Greatest_Hits.jpg");
      background-position: center, center;
      background-size: cover, 40% auto;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      border-radius: 100%;
      box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
      height: 110px;
      left: 10px;
      position: absolute;
      top: 10px;
      width: 105px;
      z-index: 5;
      will-change: transform, left;
    }

    .is-playing .vinyl {
      left: 52%;
    }

    .is-not-playing .vinyl {}


    /*
    .is-not-playing .vinyl {
    /*
    left: 0%;*/


    /*left: 1%;
    animation: none;
    transition: none;*/


    /* 
    animation:none;
    left: 5%;
    }
    */

    .i-2x {
      text-align: center;
      font-size: 2em;
    }

    [class^="control-"] {
      border-radius: 100%;
      display: inline-block;
      height: 44px;
      margin: 0 3px;
      width: 44px;
    }

    [class^="control-"]:hover {
      cursor: pointer;
    }

    .card-img-overlay > .control-play {
      /*background: transparent url("../../Content/Album/images/icon_play_blue_50.png") (top / content-box) no-repeat;*/
      background: url("https://png.icons8.com/circled-play/androidL/64");
      height: 64px;
      width: 64px;
      margin-left: 20px;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
    }

    .control-forwards {
      background: url("https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/83141/forwards.ico") center/cover no-repeat;
    }

    .control-back {
      background: url("https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/83141/backwards.ico") center/cover no-repeat;
    }

    @-webkit-keyframes spin {
      0% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
        -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
        -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
        -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
        transform: rotate(0deg);
      }
      100% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
        -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
        -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);
        -o-transform: rotate(360deg);
        transform: rotate(360deg);
      }
    }

    @-moz-keyframes spin {
      0% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
        -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
        -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
        -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
        transform: rotate(0deg);
      }
      100% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
        -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
        -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);
        -o-transform: rotate(360deg);
        transform: rotate(360deg);
      }
    }

    @-o-keyframes spin {
      0% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
        -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
        -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
        -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
        transform: rotate(0deg);
      }
      100% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
        -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
        -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);
        -o-transform: rotate(360deg);
        transform: rotate(360deg);
      }
    }

    @keyframes spin {
      0% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
        -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
        -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
        -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
        transform: rotate(0deg);
      }
      100% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
        -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
        -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);
        -o-transform: rotate(360deg);
        transform: rotate(360deg);
      }
    }
```

js-fiddle link:

[Code Link here](https://jsfiddle.net/laughingbuddha/9z0ktoha/)

Answer (score 0):

There were a few issues with your fiddle code. This was preventing the fiddle from working properly.

A. You linked to an incorrect jQuery URL, it still had `:` in the url causing it to fail to load properly. In the future use the JavaScript Library from jsFiddle.

B. You had loaded JS before CSS and this is generally unhelpful; not wrong.

So here is a working Example: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/h72rxc32/

**JavaScript**

```
$(function() {
  var $div = $('#content');
  var playButtons = $('.control-play');
  playButtons.on('click', function(e) {
    var $musiPlayerContainer = $(this).closest(".music-player-container");
    var $vinyl = $musiPlayerContainer.find('.vinyl');
    console.log($musiPlayerContainer, $vinyl);
    $(".music-player-container").not($musiPlayerContainer).toggleClass('is-playing', false);
    $musiPlayerContainer.toggleClass('is-playing', true);
    e.stopPropagation();
  });

  $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip()

  $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover()
});
```

There was no good reason not to wrap the whole code block. Using better selectors will make it a lot easier to work with and easier to understand later.

As I suspect you know, `playButtons` is all the buttons selected. In the `.on()`, we can use `$(this)` to specify the target object that was clicked. Once you have a proper relationship, the rest of your code worked as expected.